# Why does this "while read" work in a terminal, but not in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I ran into this interesting issue while populating my WM bar with info text, which is applied by setting the root window's title, i.e. `xsetroot -name "clever words"`

To this end, printing a fortune works fine in a terminal:

```
fortune -s | while read -r; do xsetroot -name "$REPLY"; done
```

Yet that same fails when run from a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /tmp/afile | while read; do echo "$REPLY"; done
```

Produces:

> $ sh afilereader
>   afilereader: 2: read: arg count

Of course this is remedied by assigning our fortune result to a variable, then using xsetroot with said variable. But I'd still like to understand *why* this does not work in a script.

I realize each command on either side of the pipeline is run within it's own subshell, but fail to see how their localized variables could affect the while read loop. Or are variables out of scope even between the loop iterations?

What am I missing?

**Update:** The `sh` I used is linked to dash, which is in the process of being made POSIX compliant. Using the more venerable `bash` solved this.

Comment: dash's behavior here doesn't manifest any falling short of POSIX compliance. POSIX doesn't require that the `read` be invocable without a variable: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to be running the first example in `bash`, and the second in whatever is pointed to by `/bin/sh`, which is a POSIX shell requiring an argument to be passed specifying the variable you wish to put the input into. Changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` should fix this.

Comment: Good observation @Chris! That works. Think I will read up a bit on the difference between `sh` and `bash`.

Comment: Abnormal indeed! I could relink `/bin/sh` to bash, but think I'd just use bash directly from now on, to avoid ambiguity. Thanks :)

Comment: Frequently interactive shells differ from shell scripts in the buffering of their output. Reading from inter-process pipes can result in all sorts of weird timing behaviors if the command generating output buffers its writes when run non-interactively.

Answer (score 4):

In sh syntax, you need

```
IFS= read -r REPLY
```

Some shells like ksh, bash and zsh allow `read` to be called without a variable name but the behavior differs between them. See for instance the output of

```
printf 'te\ st\\\na ' | "$shell" -c 'read; printf "%s\n" "<$REPLY>"'
```

differing on all of bash, zsh, pdksh and ksh93

Comment: That makes sense why the shell I was using didn't know the variable name, thanks @Stephane.